# Move css top position with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

The following code doesn't seem to work. How would I change it in order to make the div change the position from top?

```
 div { width:220px; height:170px; margin: 10px 50px 10px 10px;
    background:yellow; border:2px groove; float:right; }

 #alt { width:20px; height:170px; margin: 10px 50px 10px 10px;
        background:blue; border:2px groove; float:right; }

  #altLevel { width:10px; height:20px; 
        background:red; border:2px groove;  }



$('div').mouseclick(function() {
$( '#altLevel').css( 'top', '+=10' );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` to the styles for `#altLevel` before you can alter its position. In addition, give it a default position of `top:0` or whatever you like:

```
#altLevel { 
    width:10px; height:20px; 
    position:absolute; top:0;
    background:red; border:2px groove;  
}
```

Once you do that, your JavaScript should work with a small modification:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $('#altLevel').css('top', '+=10');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mGAKe/